# NDK error: Try to access freed memory?

Tags: android, memory, android-ndk

I upload my app to testin.cn, and some HTC and other device keep reporting this kind of error, but I can't see any thing from error log. I'll appreciate if anyone provide more information about what's going on, thank you.

error logs:

```
07-2308:53:14.269E/power(358):CannotwriteCPU_PERF_LEVEL_LOCK.(Invalidargument)
07-2308:53:14.379E/memalloc(129):ION_IOC_ALLOCfailedwitherror-Outofmemory
07-2308:53:14.409E/Trace(17929):erroropeningtracefile:Nosuchfileordirectory(2)
07-2308:53:15.159E/memalloc(129):ION_IOC_ALLOCfailedwitherror-Outofmemory
07-2308:53:15.299E/memalloc(129):ION_IOC_ALLOCfailedwitherror-Outofmemory
07-2308:53:16.279E/power(358):requestperflocklevel(0)isinvalid.(Invalidargument)
07-2308:53:17.339E/ActivityThread(17929):Failedtofindproviderinfoforcom.google.plus.platform
07-2308:53:17.549E/(17929):netstack:LIB_MGR-Errorloadinglibspl_proc_plugin.so
07-2308:53:17.549E/(17929):netstack:STAT_HUB-Failedtoloadplugin:spl_proc_plugin.so
07-2308:53:17.569E/(17929):netstack:STAT_HUB-App my.package.name isn'tsupported
07-2308:53:18.329E/(17929):netstack:LIB_MGR-Errorloadingliblibsocketpoolextend.so
07-2308:53:18.619E/memalloc(129):ION_IOC_ALLOCfailedwitherror-Outofmemory
07-2308:53:18.899E/memalloc(129):ION_IOC_ALLOCfailedwitherror-Outofmemory
07-2308:53:18.959E/memalloc(129):ION_IOC_ALLOCfailedwitherror-Outofmemory
07-2308:53:19.009E/memalloc(129):ION_IOC_ALLOCfailedwitherror-Outofmemory
07-2308:53:21.869E/webkit(17929):Exception:content://com.google.android.gms.ads.adinfo/any.gif
07-2308:53:21.869E/ActivityThread(17929):Failedtofindproviderinfoforcom.google.android.gms.ads.adinfo
07-2308:53:37.119E/ActivityThread(29742):Failedtofindproviderinfoforcom.htc.idlescreen.setting.provider
07-2308:53:37.139E/Trace(18060):erroropeningtracefile:Nosuchfileordirectory(2)
07-2308:53:37.179E/memalloc(129):ION_IOC_ALLOCfailedwitherror-Outofmemory
07-2308:53:37.559E/memalloc(129):ION_IOC_ALLOCfailedwitherror-Outofmemory
07-2308:53:37.659E/memalloc(129):ION_IOC_ALLOCfailedwitherror-Outofmemory
07-2308:53:37.829E/memalloc(129):ION_IOC_ALLOCfailedwitherror-Outofmemory
07-2308:53:38.029E/memalloc(129):ION_IOC_ALLOCfailedwitherror-Outofmemory
07-2308:53:38.169E/memalloc(129):ION_IOC_ALLOCfailedwitherror-Outofmemory
07-2308:53:38.519E/Trace(18093):erroropeningtracefile:Nosuchfileordirectory(2)
07-2308:53:39.499E/(18060):netstack:LIB_MGR-Errorloadinglibspl_proc_plugin.so
07-2308:53:39.499E/(18060):netstack:STAT_HUB-Failedtoloadplugin:spl_proc_plugin.so
07-2308:53:39.499E/ActivityThread(18060):Failedtofindproviderinfoforcom.google.plus.platform
07-2308:53:39.499E/(18060):netstack:STAT_HUB-App my.package.name isn'tsupported
07-2308:53:40.049E/(18060):netstack:LIB_MGR-Errorloadingliblibsocketpoolextend.so
07-2308:53:40.649E/webkit(18060):Exception:content://com.google.android.gms.ads.adinfo/any.gif
07-2308:53:40.649E/ActivityThread(18060):Failedtofindproviderinfoforcom.google.android.gms.ads.adinfo
07-2308:53:40.779F/libc(18137):Fatalsignal11(SIGSEGV)at0xdeadbaad(code=1),thread18137(Thread-125388)
07-2308:53:41.239E/memalloc(129):ION_IOC_ALLOCfailedwitherror-Outofmemory
07-2308:53:41.489E/memalloc(129):ION_IOC_ALLOCfailedwitherror-Outofmemory
07-2308:53:41.589E/memalloc(129):ION_IOC_ALLOCfailedwitherror-Outofmemory
07-2308:53:41.649E/memalloc(129):ION_IOC_ALLOCfailedwitherror-Outofmemory
07-2308:53:46.609E/Trace(18153):erroropeningtracefile:Nosuchfileordirectory(2)
07-2308:53:57.509E/memalloc(129):ION_IOC_ALLOCfailedwitherror-Outofmemory
07-2308:53:57.589E/memalloc(129):ION_IOC_ALLOCfailedwitherror-Outofmemory
07-2308:54:07.169E/memalloc(129):ION_IOC_ALLOCfailedwitherror-Outofmemory
07-2308:54:07.819E/memalloc(129):ION_IOC_ALLOCfailedwitherror-Outofmemory
07-2308:54:08.259E/memalloc(129):ION_IOC_ALLOCfailedwitherror-Outofmemory
07-2308:54:08.399E/memalloc(129):ION_IOC_ALLOCfailedwitherror-Outofmemory
07-2308:54:08.959E/memalloc(129):ION_IOC_ALLOCfailedwitherror-Outofmemory
07-2308:54:24.629E/memalloc(129):ION_IOC_ALLOCfailedwitherror-Outofmemory
07-2308:54:24.659E/memalloc(129):ION_IOC_ALLOCfailedwitherror-Outofmemory
07-2308:54:24.779E/memalloc(129):ION_IOC_ALLOCfailedwitherror-Outofmemory
07-2308:54:24.809E/memalloc(129):ION_IOC_ALLOCfailedwitherror-Outofmemory
07-2308:54:56.659E/memalloc(129):ION_IOC_ALLOCfailedwitherror-Outofmemory
07-2308:54:56.739E/memalloc(129):ION_IOC_ALLOCfailedwitherror-Outofmemory
07-2308:55:06.529E/memalloc(129):ION_IOC_ALLOCfailedwitherror-Outofmemory
07-2308:55:06.809E/memalloc(129):ION_IOC_ALLOCfailedwitherror-Outofmemory
07-2308:55:06.889E/memalloc(129):ION_IOC_ALLOCfailedwitherror-Outofmemory
07-2308:55:16.449E/memalloc(129):ION_IOC_ALLOCfailedwitherror-Outofmemory
07-2308:55:16.499E/memalloc(129):ION_IOC_ALLOCfailedwitherror-Outofmemory
07-2308:55:16.549E/memalloc(129):ION_IOC_ALLOCfailedwitherror-Outofmemory
07-2308:55:16.589E/memalloc(129):ION_IOC_ALLOCfailedwitherror-Outofmemory
07-2308:55:16.659E/memalloc(129):ION_IOC_ALLOCfailedwitherror-Outofmemory
07-2308:55:16.719E/memalloc(129):ION_IOC_ALLOCfailedwitherror-Outofmemory
07-2308:55:48.379E/memalloc(129):ION_IOC_ALLOCfailedwitherror-Outofmemory
07-2308:55:48.449E/memalloc(129):ION_IOC_ALLOCfailedwitherror-Outofmemory
07-2308:55:58.219E/memalloc(129):ION_IOC_ALLOCfailedwitherror-Outofmemory
07-2308:55:58.249E/power(358):CannotwriteCPU_PERF_LEVEL_LOCK.(Invalidargument)
07-2308:55:58.399E/Trace(18516):erroropeningtracefile:Nosuchfileordirectory(2)
07-2308:55:58.409E/memalloc(129):ION_IOC_ALLOCfailedwitherror-Outofmemory
07-2308:55:58.669E/Trace(18530):erroropeningtracefile:Nosuchfileordirectory(2)
07-2308:55:58.709E/ActivityThread(18516):Failedtofindproviderinfoforcom.google.settings
07-2308:55:58.709E/ActivityThread(18516):Failedtofindproviderinfoforcom.google.settings
07-2308:55:59.009E/Trace(18547):erroropeningtracefile:Nosuchfileordirectory(2)
07-2308:55:59.139E/memalloc(129):ION_IOC_ALLOCfailedwitherror-Outofmemory
07-2308:55:59.209E/memalloc(129):ION_IOC_ALLOCfailedwitherror-Outofmemory
07-2308:56:00.259E/power(358):requestperflocklevel(0)isinvalid.(Invalidargument)
07-2308:56:00.309E/(18516):netstack:LIB_MGR-Errorloadinglibspl_proc_plugin.so
07-2308:56:00.309E/Trace(18584):erroropeningtracefile:Nosuchfileordirectory(2)
07-2308:56:00.309E/(18516):netstack:STAT_HUB-Failedtoloadplugin:spl_proc_plugin.so
07-2308:56:00.609E/SQLiteLog(18516):(5)statementabortsat1:[PRAGMAjournal_mode=TRUNCATE;]
07-2308:56:00.679E/(18516):netstack:LIB_MGR-Errorloadingliblibsocketpoolextend.so
07-2308:56:00.789E/libEGL(18516):calltoOpenGLESAPIwithnocurrentcontext(loggedonceperthread)
07-2308:56:00.789E/libEGL(18516):calltoOpenGLESAPIwithnocurrentcontext(loggedonceperthread)
07-2308:56:00.789E/libEGL(18516):calltoOpenGLESAPIwithnocurrentcontext(loggedonceperthread)
07-2308:56:00.789E/libEGL(18516):calltoOpenGLESAPIwithnocurrentcontext(loggedonceperthread)
07-2308:56:00.789E/libEGL(18516):calltoOpenGLESAPIwithnocurrentcontext(loggedonceperthread)
07-2308:56:00.989E/Trace(18608):erroropeningtracefile:Nosuchfileordirectory(2)
07-2308:56:01.209E/memalloc(129):ION_IOC_ALLOCfailedwitherror-Outofmemory
07-2308:56:01.259E/memalloc(129):ION_IOC_ALLOCfailedwitherror-Outofmemory
07-2308:56:04.419E/memalloc(129):ION_IOC_ALLOCfailedwitherror-Outofmemory
07-2308:56:04.419E/Trace(18636):erroropeningtracefile:Nosuchfileordirectory(2)
07-2308:56:04.529E/power(358):CannotwriteCPU_PERF_LEVEL_LOCK.(Invalidargument)
07-2308:56:04.529E/ActivityThread(18636):Failedtofindproviderinfoforcom.google.settings
07-2308:56:04.549E/ActivityThread(18636):Failedtofindproviderinfoforcom.google.settings
07-2308:56:04.649E/memalloc(129):ION_IOC_ALLOCfailedwitherror-Outofmemory
07-2308:56:04.699E/Trace(18661):erroropeningtracefile:Nosuchfileordirectory(2)
07-2308:56:05.049E/(18636):netstack:LIB_MGR-Errorloadinglibspl_proc_plugin.so
07-2308:56:05.049E/(18636):netstack:STAT_HUB-Failedtoloadplugin:spl_proc_plugin.so
07-2308:56:05.099E/Trace(18682):erroropeningtracefile:Nosuchfileordirectory(2)
07-2308:56:05.159E/Trace(18695):erroropeningtracefile:Nosuchfileordirectory(2)
07-2308:56:05.359E/(18636):netstack:LIB_MGR-Errorloadingliblibsocketpoolextend.so
07-2308:56:05.639E/SQLiteLog(18636):(5)statementabortsat1:[PRAGMAjournal_mode=TRUNCATE;]
07-2308:56:05.919E/memalloc(129):ION_IOC_ALLOCfailedwitherror-Outofmemory
07-2308:56:05.929E/power(358):CannotwriteCPU_PERF_LEVEL_LOCK.(Invalidargument)
07-2308:56:06.049E/memalloc(129):ION_IOC_ALLOCfailedwitherror-Outofmemory
07-2308:56:06.339E/Trace(18740):erroropeningtracefile:Nosuchfileordirectory(2)
07-2308:56:06.989E/libEGL(18636):calltoOpenGLESAPIwithnocurrentcontext(loggedonceperthread)
07-2308:56:06.989E/libEGL(18636):calltoOpenGLESAPIwithnocurrentcontext(loggedonceperthread)
07-2308:56:06.989E/libEGL(18636):calltoOpenGLESAPIwithnocurrentcontext(loggedonceperthread)
07-2308:56:06.989E/libEGL(18636):calltoOpenGLESAPIwithnocurrentcontext(loggedonceperthread)
07-2308:56:06.989E/libEGL(18636):calltoOpenGLESAPIwithnocurrentcontext(loggedonceperthread)
07-2308:56:07.489E/Trace(18763):erroropeningtracefile:Nosuchfileordirectory(2)
07-2308:56:07.509E/memalloc(129):ION_IOC_ALLOCfailedwitherror-Outofmemory
07-2308:56:07.579E/power(358):CannotwriteCPU_PERF_LEVEL_LOCK.(Invalidargument)
07-2308:56:07.639E/memalloc(129):ION_IOC_ALLOCfailedwitherror-Outofmemory
07-2308:56:07.709E/ActivityThread(18763):Failedtofindproviderinfoforcom.google.settings
07-2308:56:07.709E/ActivityThread(18763):Failedtofindproviderinfoforcom.google.settings
07-2308:56:07.739E/Trace(18781):erroropeningtracefile:Nosuchfileordirectory(2)
07-2308:56:07.809E/Trace(18797):erroropeningtracefile:Nosuchfileordirectory(2)
07-2308:56:08.179E/Trace(18812):erroropeningtracefile:Nosuchfileordirectory(2)
07-2308:56:08.239E/ActivityThread(18740):Failedtofindproviderinfoforcom.tencent.mm.coolassist.debugprovider
07-2308:56:08.639E/memalloc(129):ION_IOC_ALLOCfailedwitherror-Outofmemory
07-2308:56:08.679E/Trace(18831):erroropeningtracefile:Nosuchfileordirectory(2)
07-2308:56:08.749E/(18763):netstack:LIB_MGR-Errorloadinglibspl_proc_plugin.so
07-2308:56:08.749E/(18763):netstack:STAT_HUB-Failedtoloadplugin:spl_proc_plugin.so
07-2308:56:08.879E/Trace(18846):erroropeningtracefile:Nosuchfileordirectory(2)
07-2308:56:08.979E/memalloc(129):ION_IOC_ALLOCfailedwitherror-Outofmemory
07-2308:56:09.219E/(18763):netstack:LIB_MGR-Errorloadingliblibsocketpoolextend.so
07-2308:56:09.239E/SQLiteLog(18763):(5)statementabortsat1:[PRAGMAjournal_mode=TRUNCATE;]
07-2308:56:09.459E/power(358):CannotwriteCPU_PERF_LEVEL_LOCK.(Invalidargument)
07-2308:56:09.729E/libEGL(18763):calltoOpenGLESAPIwithnocurrentcontext(loggedonceperthread)
07-2308:56:09.729E/libEGL(18763):calltoOpenGLESAPIwithnocurrentcontext(loggedonceperthread)
07-2308:56:09.729E/libEGL(18763):calltoOpenGLESAPIwithnocurrentcontext(loggedonceperthread)
07-2308:56:09.729E/libEGL(18763):calltoOpenGLESAPIwithnocurrentcontext(loggedonceperthread)
07-2308:56:09.729E/libEGL(18763):calltoOpenGLESAPIwithnocurrentcontext(loggedonceperthread)
07-2308:56:10.149E/(18812):netstack:LIB_MGR-Errorloadinglibspl_proc_plugin.so
07-2308:56:10.149E/(18812):netstack:STAT_HUB-Failedtoloadplugin:spl_proc_plugin.so
07-2308:56:10.159E/(18812):netstack:STAT_HUB-App my.package.name isn'tsupported
07-2308:56:10.189E/ActivityThread(18812):Failedtofindproviderinfoforcom.google.plus.platform
07-2308:56:10.649E/(18812):netstack:LIB_MGR-Errorloadingliblibsocketpoolextend.so
07-2308:56:11.019E/webkit(18812):Exception:content://com.google.android.gms.ads.adinfo/any.gif
07-2308:56:11.019E/ActivityThread(18812):Failedtofindproviderinfoforcom.google.android.gms.ads.adinfo
07-2308:56:11.119F/libc(18911):Fatalsignal11(SIGSEGV)at0xdeadbaad(code=1),thread18911(Thread-125434)
07-2308:56:11.689E/memalloc(129):ION_IOC_ALLOCfailedwitherror-Outofmemory
07-2308:56:11.959E/memalloc(129):ION_IOC_ALLOCfailedwitherror-Outofmemory
07-2308:56:12.049E/memalloc(129):ION_IOC_ALLOCfailedwitherror-Outofmemory
07-2308:56:12.169E/memalloc(129):ION_IOC_ALLOCfailedwitherror-Outofmemory
07-2308:56:14.649E/Trace(18946):erroropeningtracefile:Nosuchfileordirectory(2)
07-2308:56:15.029E/memalloc(129):ION_IOC_ALLOCfailedwitherror-Outofmemory
07-2308:56:15.069E/memalloc(129):ION_IOC_ALLOCfailedwitherror-Outofmemory
07-2308:56:17.049E/memalloc(129):ION_IOC_ALLOCfailedwitherror-Outofmemory
07-2308:56:17.089E/memalloc(129):ION_IOC_ALLOCfailedwitherror-Outofmemory
07-2308:56:17.169E/memalloc(129):ION_IOC_ALLOCfailedwitherror-Outofmemory
07-2308:56:17.199E/memalloc(129):ION_IOC_ALLOCfailedwitherror-Outofmemory
07-2308:56:19.169E/memalloc(129):ION_IOC_ALLOCfailedwitherror-Outofmemory
07-2308:56:19.179E/Trace(18970):erroropeningtracefile:Nosuchfileordirectory(2)
07-2308:56:19.369E/memalloc(129):ION_IOC_ALLOCfailedwitherror-Outofmemory
07-2308:56:19.769E/memalloc(129):ION_IOC_ALLOCfailedwitherror-Outofmemory
07-2308:56:19.799E/memalloc(129):ION_IOC_ALLOCfailedwitherror-Outofmemory
07-2308:56:20.629E/power(358):CannotwriteCPU_PERF_LEVEL_LOCK.(Invalidargument)
07-2308:56:20.729E/memalloc(129):ION_IOC_ALLOCfailedwitherror-Outofmemory
07-2308:56:20.769E/memalloc(129):ION_IOC_ALLOCfailedwitherror-Outofmemory
07-2308:56:21.029E/power(358):requestperflocklevel(0)isinvalid.(Invalidargument)
07-2308:56:25.309E/memalloc(129):ION_IOC_ALLOCfailedwitherror-Outofmemory
07-2308:56:25.339E/memalloc(129):ION_IOC_ALLOCfailedwitherror-Outofmemory
07-2308:56:25.379E/memalloc(129):ION_IOC_ALLOCfailedwitherror-Outofmemory
07-2308:56:25.409E/memalloc(129):ION_IOC_ALLOCfailedwitherror-Outofmemory
07-2308:56:25.479E/memalloc(129):ION_IOC_ALLOCfailedwitherror-Outofmemory
07-2308:56:25.539E/memalloc(129):ION_IOC_ALLOCfailedwitherror-Outofmemory
07-2308:56:25.769E/memalloc(129):ION_IOC_ALLOCfailedwitherror-Outofmemory
07-2308:56:25.809E/memalloc(129):ION_IOC_ALLOCfailedwitherror-Outofmemory
07-2308:56:29.319E/power(358):CannotwriteCPU_PERF_LEVEL_LOCK.(Invalidargument)
07-2308:56:29.389E/memalloc(129):ION_IOC_ALLOCfailedwitherror-Outofmemory
07-2308:56:29.419E/memalloc(129):ION_IOC_ALLOCfailedwitherror-Outofmemory
07-2308:56:31.289E/power(358):requestperflocklevel(0)isinvalid.(Invalidargument)
07-2308:56:31.789E/lights(358):[LedErr]openattrfailedname=/sys/class/leds/amber/brightnesserrno:2
07-2308:56:31.789E/lights(358):[LedErr]openattrfailedname=/sys/class/leds/amber/blinkerrno:2
07-2308:56:31.789E/lights(358):[LedErr]openattrfailedname=/sys/class/leds/amber/off_timererrno:2
07-2308:56:31.789E/lights(358):[LedErr]openattrfailedname=/sys/class/leds/green/brightnesserrno:2
07-2308:56:31.789E/lights(358):[LedErr]openattrfailedname=/sys/class/leds/green/blinkerrno:2
07-2308:56:31.789E/lights(358):[LedErr]openattrfailedname=/sys/class/leds/green/off_timererrno:2
07-2308:56:31.819E/memalloc(129):ION_IOC_ALLOCfailedwitherror-Outofmemory
07-2308:56:31.869E/memalloc(129):ION_IOC_ALLOCfailedwitherror-Outofmemory
07-2308:56:31.899E/memalloc(129):ION_IOC_ALLOCfailedwitherror-Outofmemory
07-2308:56:34.669E/Trace(19051):erroropeningtracefile:Nosuchfileordirectory(2)
07-2308:56:36.879E/power(358):CannotwriteCPU_PERF_LEVEL_LOCK.(Invalidargument)
07-2308:56:36.899E/lights(358):[LedErr]openattrfailedname=/sys/class/leds/amber/brightnesserrno:2
07-2308:56:36.899E/lights(358):[LedErr]openattrfailedname=/sys/class/leds/amber/blinkerrno:2
07-2308:56:36.899E/lights(358):[LedErr]openattrfailedname=/sys/class/leds/amber/off_timererrno:2
07-2308:56:36.899E/lights(358):[LedErr]openattrfailedname=/sys/class/leds/green/brightnesserrno:2
07-2308:56:36.899E/lights(358):[LedErr]openattrfailedname=/sys/class/leds/green/blinkerrno:2
07-2308:56:36.899E/lights(358):[LedErr]openattrfailedname=/sys/class/leds/green/off_timererrno:2
07-2308:56:37.089E/memalloc(129):ION_IOC_ALLOCfailedwitherror-Outofmemory
07-2308:56:37.119E/memalloc(129):ION_IOC_ALLOCfailedwitherror-Outofmemory
07-2308:56:37.149E/memalloc(129):ION_IOC_ALLOCfailedwitherror-Outofmemory
07-2308:56:37.179E/memalloc(129):ION_IOC_ALLOCfailedwitherror-Outofmemory
07-2308:56:37.259E/memalloc(129):ION_IOC_ALLOCfailedwitherror-Outofmemory
07-2308:56:37.339E/memalloc(129):ION_IOC_ALLOCfailedwitherror-Outofmemory
07-2308:56:37.869E/memalloc(129):ION_IOC_ALLOCfailedwitherror-Outofmemory
07-2308:56:37.909E/memalloc(129):ION_IOC_ALLOCfailedwitherror-Outofmemory
07-2308:56:38.889E/power(358):requestperflocklevel(0)isinvalid.(Invalidargument)
07-2308:56:39.829E/power(358):CannotwriteCPU_PERF_LEVEL_LOCK.(Invalidargument)
07-2308:56:39.889E/memalloc(129):ION_IOC_ALLOCfailedwitherror-Outofmemory
07-2308:56:39.929E/memalloc(129):ION_IOC_ALLOCfailedwitherror-Outofmemory
07-2308:56:41.779E/power(358):requestperflocklevel(0)isinvalid.(Invalidargument)
07-2308:56:44.699E/Trace(19102):erroropeningtracefile:Nosuchfileordirectory(2)
07-2308:56:46.269E/lights(358):[LedErr]openattrfailedname=/sys/class/leds/amber/brightnesserrno:2
07-2308:56:46.269E/lights(358):[LedErr]openattrfailedname=/sys/class/leds/amber/blinkerrno:2
07-2308:56:46.269E/lights(358):[LedErr]openattrfailedname=/sys/class/leds/amber/off_timererrno:2
07-2308:56:46.269E/lights(358):[LedErr]openattrfailedname=/sys/class/leds/green/brightnesserrno:2
07-2308:56:46.269E/lights(358):[LedErr]openattrfailedname=/sys/class/leds/green/blinkerrno:2
07-2308:56:46.269E/lights(358):[LedErr]openattrfailedname=/sys/class/leds/green/off_timererrno:2
07-2308:56:46.459E/memalloc(129):ION_IOC_ALLOCfailedwitherror-Outofmemory
07-2308:56:49.799E/Trace(19151):erroropeningtracefile:Nosuchfileordirectory(2)
```

Comment: Android devices are often quite noisy about unrelated minor issues.  What messages in the list match names of your package, ndk libraries, or known log tags?

Comment: "netstack:STAT_HUB-App my.package.name isn'tsupported" I got this report from a auto-monkey-test website.